Consume InputIterator with C++ ranges
With an input iterator, I can consume different sub-ranges out of it, e.g.
void test(std::input_iterator auto it) {
  while (*it < 1) ++it; // drop_while
  int n = *it; ++it; // take(1)
  int sum = 0; for (; n-- > 0; ++it) sum += (1 + *it); // fold_left(take(n) | transform)
  int prd = 1; for (; int x = *it / 2; ++it) prd *= x; // fold_left(transform | take_while)
  std::cout << sum << ' ' << prd << '\n';
}

int main() {
    test(std::begin({0, 0, 0, 3, 400, 30, 2, 4, 6, 0}));
}

Is there a way to do the same with std::ranges/std::views?

I tried a bit and I don't think there's a way. most STL functors requiring viewable_range will force you to pass rvalue input_range and prevent you from managing the lifetime your own. and there is no generic way to elevate an input_range to some other contracts.

N.b. your std::input_iterator code is invalid for some input iterators, as it++ can have any type, including void

@Caleth, right, removed *it++

The problem is that in algo(range | view_with_a_sentinel), the algorithm doesn't receive the original range, so it cannot return the unconsumed part of the range.
However, with all those views, and ranges, deep inside there is an iterator which gets incremented. If we get this iterator, we can construct another range.
So the answer is: use indirection.
Let's write an input iterator that has a reference to another input iterator.
template<std::input_iterator I>
struct IterProxy : std::iterator_traits<I> {
    std::reference_wrapper<I> it{};
    IterProxy(I& it) : it{it} {}

    using iterator_concept = std::input_iterator_tag;

    auto operator*() const { return *it.get(); }
    auto& operator++() { ++it.get(); return *this; }
    void operator++(int) { ++it.get(); }

    friend auto operator<=>(IterProxy, IterProxy) = default;
    friend auto operator==(IterProxy p, I i) { return p.it.get() == i; }
    friend auto operator==(I i, IterProxy p) { return p.it.get() == i; }
};

Now we can use this proxy instead of an actual range, so we would always keep track of an original input iterator:
void test_ranges(std::ranges::input_range auto range) {
  auto it{std::ranges::begin(range)}, last{std::ranges::end(range)};
  auto tail = std::ranges::subrange(IterProxy{it}, last);

  algo1(tail | view | ...);
  algo2(tail | view | ...);
}

Here is the code from the question, with ranges:
void test_ranges(std::ranges::input_range auto range) {
  auto it{std::ranges::begin(range)}, last{std::ranges::end(range)};
  auto tail = std::ranges::subrange(IterProxy{it}, last);
  int n = *std::ranges::begin(tail | std::views::drop_while([](auto x) { return x < 1; }));
  ++it; // could be begin(tail | take(1))
  int sum = std::ranges::fold_left(
      tail | std::views::take(n) | std::views::transform([](auto x) { return x + 1; }),
      0, [](auto sum, auto x) { return sum + x; });
  int prd = std::ranges::fold_left(
      tail | std::views::transform([](auto x) { return x / 2; }) | std::views::take_while([](auto x) { return x != 0; }),
      1, [](auto prd, auto x) { return prd * x; });
  std::cout << sum << ' ' << prd << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::istringstream in{"0 0 0   3   400 30 2   4 6   0"};
  std::istream_iterator<int> first{in}, last;
  test_ranges(std::ranges::subrange{first, last});
}

https://godbolt.org/z/4zGscYvs4

its still not enough to pass std::generator

edit: added some boilerplates to work with std::generator godbolt

next issue then... these algos are supposed to be functional and have no side effects :(

I'd spell the comparison auto operator==(IterProxy p, std::sentinel_for<I> auto i), and you only need one

You can also express calculating n as a left fold, which gets you this sketchy thing

@Caleth well, maybe ranges cannot replace iterators yet.

Generally speaking, no. At least it won't conform with std::ranges::view_interface nor std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure
Essentially all the views / adaptors you mentioned requires the std::ranges::viewable_range concept, which forbids any lvalue input_range, implying you must handover ownership to the adaptors used which could not be splited across all.
It should be noted that OP provided an array as test range, which is a forward_range and less strict than input_range, i.e. it supports multi-pass instead of single-pass. A better test would be ...
std::generator<int> test_range() {
    static constexpr auto data = {0, 0, 0, 3, 400, 30, 2, 4, 6, 0};
    for(int num: data) {
        co_yield num;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto data = test_range();
    static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<decltype(data)>);
    test(data);
}

This ought not be interpreted as std::ranges / std::views is less powerful than <algorithm> or <numeric> though, since std::accumulate(it, it+n, ...) creates a copy of the iterator.
Never the less OP have raised a good example that managing your own iterator stays more powerful than depending on STL utilities.

Welp, in fact, it is possible. Please see my answer.

Yes, you can use std::ranges and std::views to rewrite test function:
void test(std::ranges::input_range auto&& rng) {
  using std::views::drop_while;
  using std::views::take;
  using std::views::transform;

  auto drop_less_than_one = drop_while(rng, [](int x) { return x < 1; });
  auto n = *drop_less_than_one.begin();

  auto take_n = drop_less_than_one | drop_while([](int x) { return x < 1; }) | take(n);
  int sum = std::accumulate(take_n.begin(), take_n.end(), 0, [](int acc, int x) {
    return acc + (1 + x);
  });

  auto half = transform(drop_less_than_one, [](int x) { return x / 2; });
  auto take_while_half = half | std::views::take_while([](int x) { return x > 0; });
  int prd = std::accumulate(take_while_half.begin(), take_while_half.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>());

  std::cout << sum << ' ' << prd << '\n';
}


Your code does not work for all input range, godbolt. You are confusing input range with forward range

You can create new ranges that represents a sub-range.  I've added to your example:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

void test(std::input_iterator auto it) {
  while (*it < 1) ++it; // drop_while
  int n = *it++; // take(1)
  int sum = 0; while (n-- > 0) sum += (1 + *it++); // fold_left(take(n) | transform)
  int prd = 1; while (int x = *it++ / 2) prd *= x; // fold_left(transform | take_while)
  std::cout << sum << ' ' << prd << '\n';
}

void test_ranges(std::ranges::forward_range auto range) {
    auto a = range | std::views::drop_while([](auto x) { return x < 1; });
    const auto n = *std::ranges::begin(a);
    auto b = a | std::views::drop(1);

    auto sum = 0;
    std::ranges::for_each(b | std::views::take(n) | std::views::transform([](auto x) { return 1 + x; }), [&sum](auto x) { sum += x; });
    auto c = b | std::views::drop(n);
    
    auto prd = 1;
    std::ranges::for_each(c | std::views::transform([](auto x) { return x / 2; }) | std::views::take_while([](auto x) { return x; }), [&prd](auto x) { prd *= x; });
    std::cout << sum << ' ' << prd << '\n';
}

int main() {
    const auto data = std::array{0, 0, 0, 3, 400, 30, 2, 4, 6, 0};
    test(std::begin(data));
    test_ranges(data);
}


Your code does not work for all input range, godbolt. You are confusing input range with forward range

@haleyk I've updated the example to use forward_range.  I don't see anything in the question that requires input_range.

@PsychoInferno the example in the OP is (accidentally?) a random_access_range but the intent is to accept any input_range

@PsychoInferno test() takes an input iterator and does 11 *it and 10 ++it. test_ranges() with a forward_range does 21 *it, 19 ++it. https://godbolt.org/z/6xx9bsjaT
Also "InputIterator" literally is in the title, for the reason.
